# Choosing a suitable loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

What is the best way to allow the following to be in a loop for 1 hour and have a 5 minute  sleep? I have tried one loop which used stopwatch but that caused an error when trying to run it in debug.

```
string message = txtmessage.Text;
Clipboard.SetText(message);
SendKeys.SendWait("x");
SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Perhaps a timer? Note that this type of code is *extremely* fragile and probably not the correct way to do whatever it is that you're trying to do. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: StopWatch didnt work because it is a diagnostic measure. You could use a  DateTime object that will check the TimeSpan to see if 1 hour has ellapsed. The 5 minute sleep it will be for every 1 hour or in between ?

Comment: I need the program to do some input a user would do. When in-game it will press 'x' which brings up the chat box and then paste a message into it which a user puts into the text box 'txtmessage' and hits enter. I have found out that it does it more than once which I can't seem to find a solution on google.

Comment: I had a look at datetime and it just states about using days instead of hours and minutes, could you provide me with a piece of code?

Comment: @ConnorNee Take a look at [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=timer+in+C%23&rlz=1C1CHWL_enIR739IR739&oq=timer+in+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3006j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I currently have this now:
https://pastebin.com/n3ZbDkHa and get this error: https://gyazo.com/ab1f006417886116cc9bbbd08e47a42e

Comment: There is no shortage of questions on Stack Overflow already discussing how to perform some arbitrary operation on some periodic basis. See marked duplicates for three of the highest-voted examples. There's not enough context in your question to know what the best option for you would be. Something like `System.Threading.Timer` would work well for a console program. In a GUI program, you could use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (Winforms) or `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` (WPF), but modern C# has `async`/`await`, which you can use with `Task.Delay()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StopWatch didnt work because it is a diagnostic measure. You could use a DateTime object that will check the TimeSpan to see if 1 hour has ellapsed. The 5 minute sleep it will be for every 1 hour or in between ?

You can do it like this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
Console.WriteLine($"It will stop at: {dateTime}");
var now = DateTime.Now;
while (dateTime.CompareTo(now) > 0)
{
   //Do Job
   now = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Note that this is the simplest way i can think of. You can change it and make it better.

**EDIT:** 
This version of code uses Thread sleep and Timer to do the job you want. Be very careful when you calling the `Thread.Sleep` though because you can freeze your app if it put to sleep the ui thread of your app.

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Started at: {DateTime.Now}");
 Timer timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds) 
 {AutoReset = true};
 timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //Your code here.
        };
 timer.Start();

 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

 timer.Stop();
```

Comment: the loop will run for 1 hour but the code should only be executed every 5 minutes within that 1 hour.

Comment: Anyone know what this error is for? 
https://pastebin.com/84T3Z6UM

Referring to this: https://pastebin.com/BKPftni9

Comment: Your OnTimedEvent does not match the signature i think. By the way check my newest edit. I utilised what @Media said about the timer.

Comment: What does it do btw? also I get this erro using it https://gyazo.com/2a9f367757be5d729aaf5cf2a3c6eaaf

Comment: The timer will launch an event every 5 seconds in my case, it will reset every time it reaches its limit. Then i use the thread.Sleep  and after x minutes i stop the timer. (I could do some clean up to at this point.) EDIT: For your error link can you provide the code that threw the exception ?

Comment: I don't know how to find the code that threw it

Comment: You could use the stacktrace to check the path of method calls that threw the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147005/discussion-between-connor-nee-and-nick-polideropoulos).